# Can't use Cut, Copy, Paste function with Jupyter Notebook extension v2021.6.999662501 in VS Code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

Can't use **Cut, Copy, Paste** function with Jupyter Notebook extension **v2021.6.999662501** in VS Code.  This feature was working without issue before but after the latest update can't seem to get this to work at all. Right-click also does not show any options for cut, copy and paste of selected item.

Comment: I don't know if this is the same issue, but in case: as of my latest vscode update I need to use `c` instead of `cmd + c` to copy any output in jupyter.

Comment: Not expecting this answer but it's true, just `c` copies cell output on Mac OS.

Comment: I have the same problem - but on windows. C don't seem to work. Any solution? Thx